# how to test/debug the bot using remote endpoint

Tags: emulation, botframework

I developed a bot on my machine (http://localhost:3999), and it is published on some endpoint "http://botone-np-webapp.azurewebsites.net/api/messages" using WebChat channel i can use it. I would like to test and debug "http://botone-np-webapp.azurewebsites.net/api/messages" instead of localhost:3999/api/messages.

I have provided the MicrosoftAppId and Micsodoftpassword also. but not working, in emulator.

how do I test this in emulator.?

Comment: Have you tried to type "https" instead of "http" in above-mentioned URL?

Comment: You need a network tunnel in order for the bot to send messages back to your emulator. The Bot Framework emulator integrates closely with ngrok (www.ngrok.com) for this purpose. Do you have ngrok installed and its path configured in the emulator? (https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-emulator/wiki/Tunneling-(ngrok))